# What is the purpose of waffle irons that flip?

Tags: equipment, waffle

I saw some local shops selling waffle irons that have a complicated gimbal mechanism (such as the Bella Rotating Waffle Maker listed [here](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Bella-Rotating-Waffle-Maker/100677205)). What is the purpose of begin able to turn the waffle within this device? Does this have any advantage over a regular waffle iron that just has a top lid that opens?

Comment: Is it like this one? [*Cuisinart Griddler*](https://www.cuisinart.com/products/grills/gr-4n/) This has interchangeable grill plates (including ones for waffles). The hinged part on the top is to accommodate thick items like sandwich or panini. A photo or reference to a model would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some waffle irons flip to evenly spread the batter. This is important in commercial applications where the visual presentation of the product is crucial and can save on batter - you can use less batter to get a thick, complete waffle.

The waffle iron presses rely on the expansion of the batter to create a complete waffle. Sometimes in order to get a full, thick waffle, you have to use a little more batter, which often ends up spilling over to the side. It's a trade-off - if you don't want spills, use less batter with the potential for a slightly incomplete waffle.'

From eBay's [Waffle Maker Buying Guide](http://www.ebay.com/gds/Waffle-Maker-Buying-Guide-/10000000177632705/g.html) - "This ensures even cooking, and it ensures that batter is evenly distributed. There's less risk of ending up with a waffle that has holes."